# string error in C

Tags: c, string, syntax-error

```
  void mark(char arr[],int s[][50],int i,int j){
   if(j>i)
      arr = "("+mark(arr,s,i,s[i][j])+"*"+ mark(arr,s,s[i][j]+1,j)+ ")";
   else
      sprintf(arr, "%s%d", "M",i);

  }
```

When I complie this I get an error: void value not ignored as it ought to be. Now arr is a character array large enough to store the value of the ultimate brackets and alphabets generated. I am trying to implement this code in C but I am a complete beginner. Can somebody please tell me how to concatenate strings(like using the '+' operator in javascript). Any suggestion on where to start learning C (for beginners) will also be deeply appreciated.

Comment: your function cannot be declared in this way. Is this your actual code? If not, please post the right code.

Comment: This isn't C. Do you mean JavaScript?

Comment: is this is the C programming ?

Comment: As a side node: It seems that you're new to C. string manipulation is a tricky thing in C and can lead to tons of errors. You might be better off with C++ and the use of std::string.

Comment: Now it looks more like C, thanks for the edit. What does the mark function with only three arguments?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the problem with the string handling, you call the `mark` function recursively inside the expression, expecting a result. However, you declared it as returning `void` and you never actually return anything from the function.

**Edit:** How about something like this (untested!):

```
char *mark(char arr[], int s[][50], int i, int j)
{
    if (j > i)
    {
        sprintf(arr, "(%s * %s)",
            mark(arr, s, i, s[i][j]),
            mark(arr, s, s[i][j] + 1, j));
    }
    else
        sprintf(arr, "M%d", i);

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to return anything I pass an array arr and I want it to store the answer. I just print it in the main function when needed. What is wrong with that?

Comment: Vivec: You are using the `+` operator on the return value from `mark`. The `+` operator does not work on `void` type arguments.

Comment: @VivekPradhan - have you tried PHP or Python or JavaScript? They may be more suitable for your problem.

Comment: @Joe,I need to implement this using C only.

Comment: @VivekPradhan then you should read some books on C. There are some parts of your question that indicate that you do not understand the language fundamentals.

Comment: @VivekPradhan Then I suggest you start with something more basic, to learn how to handle strings, and what declaring a function to return `void` means.

Comment: I got you, but can you give me an idea of how do i go about this problem. I understand recursion and now I know i am trying to add a string to a void value so it gives me an error. But is there no other way to add strings other than strcat or looking at all the characters one by one and putting them into another character array.

Comment: @VivekPradhan Then you could modify the function to return `arr`, so it could be used in e.g. `strcat`, or in `sprintf` like in my modified answer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanx a lot for your snippet. I tried using it by calling mark as follows:    printf("%s",mark(arr,s,1,n));                   It complied fine.But I do not see any output when i run it.

Comment: @VivekPradhan Output from functions like `printf` is buffered, but if you end the output with a newline it will work better. I.e. `printf("%s\n", ...);`

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you can't add strings the way you're trying to. That doesn't fly in C.
However, this error:

```
error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

Has nothing to do with that problem. That is because you're trying to use the return from a function that returns nothing.

```
  void mark(char arr[],int s[][50],int i,int j) //void means it returns nothing

    arr = "("+mark(arr,s,i,s[i][j])+      // This says store into arr "(" + nothing
```

The compiler doesn't know what to do with that statement so it throws the error you noted above. Once you fix that problem (by add a return to mark() or whatever you want to do to fix it), you'll get an error like this:

```
error C2110: '+' : cannot add two pointers
```

or:

```
error: invalid operands to binary + (have ‘char *’ and ‘char *’)
```

or something like that depending on your compiler. That's because, as you mentioned, you can't add strings like that in C. For concatenating your strings, you'll need to use strcat:

```
char str_one[1024] = "hello";  //something big enough for whatever your putting in it... size is up to you
char str_two[] = " world";
strcat(str_one, str_two);      //str_one now has "hello world"
```